# Magento 2- How to pre select and load CCAvenue on checkout page

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, checkout-page, magento2ccavenue

I have installed and configure the CCAvenue payment method in Magento 2.3 successfully, now I want to **pre-select and load CCAvenue** on the payment section.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

can you please check this free extension [Auto Select Shipping Payment Method](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-pre-select-shipping-payment.html)

OR

check this solution [magento-2-how-to-auto-select-and-load-the-first-payment-method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143803/magento-2-how-to-auto-select-and-load-the-first-payment-method)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but the 
The first solution is only compatible with Magento 2.2, and 
the second option is for Braintree, this is not working for me.

Comment: can you use Magekmf_Ccavenue module?

Comment: Thanks  @chandresh Chauhan, Actually I am at the last phase of the website and almost done everything except the above task, implementing a new module in the last phase may create some issue, please suggest something else.

Comment: Auto select shipping payment method - extension working properly in Magento 2.3 also